# API Always 401 with valid token .NET 7

Tags: c#, .net, jwt

I'm configuring my API to use JWT token authentication, the end-points without Authorize attribute works, when I'm configuring it does not work anymore.

First I'm disabling Validate Issuer and Audience, still the same thing

The order of declare app.UseAuthentication() app.UseAuthorization()  has verified

JWT Config:

```
 public static class AuthenticationExtension
    {
        public static void AddAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var jwtAppSettingOptions = configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtOptions));
            var securityKey = jwtAppSettingOptions[(nameof(JwtOptions.SecurityKey))]?.Trim() ?? string.Empty;
            var jwtSecurityKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(securityKey);
            var symmetricSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(jwtSecurityKey);
            var tokenValidationsParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = symmetricSecurityKey,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[(nameof(JwtOptions.Issuer))]?.Trim() ?? string.Empty,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidAudience = jwtAppSettingOptions[(nameof(JwtOptions.Audiance))]?.Trim() ?? string.Empty,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
            };

            services.Configure<JwtOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Issuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[(nameof(JwtOptions.Issuer))]?.Trim() ?? string.Empty;
                options.Audiance = jwtAppSettingOptions[(nameof(JwtOptions.Audiance))]?.Trim() ?? string.Empty;
                options.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(symmetricSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
                options.AccessTokenExpiration = uint.Parse(jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtOptions.AccessTokenExpiration)] ?? "0");
                options.RefreshTokenExpiration = uint.Parse(jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtOptions.RefreshTokenExpiration)] ?? "0");
            });

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            });

            services
                .AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.SaveToken = true;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationsParameters;
                });
        }
    }
```

Program.cs config:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            builder.Services.AddCors();
            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            builder.Services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
            builder.Services.AddSwagger();
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(builder.Configuration);
            builder.Services.RegisterDependencies(builder.Configuration);

            var app = builder.Build();

            app.UseSwaggerUI();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseCors(builder => builder
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(orign => true)
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.MapControllers();

            app.Run();
        }
    }
```

End-Point Config:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Ping() => Ok("Success");
```

Write Token:

```
private async Task<UsuarioDTO.AutenticarRetorno> ObterRetornoAutenticadoAsync(string email)
        {
            var usuario = await ObterUsuarioAsync(email);
            var claims = await ObterClaimsAsync(usuario);
            var dataExpiracao = DateTime.Now.AddHours(_options.AccessTokenExpiration);
            var securityTokenDescriptior = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Issuer = _options.Issuer,
                Audience = _options.Audiance,
                Expires = dataExpiracao,
                NotBefore = DateTime.Now,
                SigningCredentials = _options.SigningCredentials,
            };

            var jwt = _handler.CreateToken(securityTokenDescriptior);
            var token = _handler.WriteToken(jwt);

            return new UsuarioDTO.AutenticarRetorno(token, dataExpiracao);
        }
```

[The token generated is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tId8i.png)

[but always requisitions with POSTMAN returns 401](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C9dT.png)

First add the following code:

```
services
            .AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationsParameters;
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = c =>
                    {
                        // break point here
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                };
            });
```

When debugging the application with a breakpoint I'm seeing the error
[Error in debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCXIi.png)

To solve it I'm installing the NuGet package on the Web API project
**System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt**

Comment: If you've already solved the issue, simply delete the question. Or, add an answer (see [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for tips). Do not edit the question to add SOLVED to the title or add the solution to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the Heretic support, I can't add an answer to my question because my reputation level is not enabled, but I want to leave this history to myself.